# How to offset an entire row

Tags: vba

I have table where the rows consists of names, and the Y axis has categories. Each row has a number 1 through 5 filled under certain columns. I'm developing a Macro where i can get a match for the column position based on row number and number(1-5) that I'm searching for

Right now, despite what row number I'm on, I'm getting the position of columns based on what ever values are in the first row. I could be trying to search the 3rd row but I'm getting the matching figures for the first row

Can anyone tell me how to ensure my range is offset to a new row

```
Sub StructurePivot2()
Dim X As Variant, Var As Double, P As Integer, Z As Integer, ws As Worksheet, rng3 As Range, category As Variant, rng As Range, cell As Variant, i As Integer, rng2 As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A173")
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:AI2")
Set rng3 = rng2.offset(P)
P = 0

For Each cell In rng
    Set rng3 = rng2.Offset(P)
    For i = 1 To 5
        Z = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(i, rng3, 0)
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").Offset(P, 3) = Z
        P = P + 1
    Next i
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to add to this. If i replace P with an actual number, it repeats all the values from that row number, but with P it sticks with Row # 1 or throws an error sometime regarding the match. It's very confusing

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are looking for from your description. If you describe your data structure (with an image or something), it'll get easier to understand.
Having that said (and still without understanding your scenario), the P increment inside the inner loop and reading it in the outer loop looks suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is that `P` is incremented in the inner loop and never restarted back to 0. Concerning the Mismatch error, it is because no match is found. Thus, try to turn back`P` to `0` for every `cell` and write the `rng3.Address` to the immediate window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to see where the error is:

```
For Each cell In Rng
    For i = 1 To 5
        Set rng3 = rng2.Offset(P)
        Debug.Print rng3.Address
        Z = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(i, rng3, 0)
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").Offset(P, 3) = Z
        P = P + 1
    Next i
    P = 0
Next cell
```